# How to write a script that will paste signatures into a textbox using tampermonkey (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, textbox, tampermonkey

Hello I want to write a script that pastes a phrase automatically into text boxes on a forum. How may I do this? Tampermonkey already allows me to only activate the script on a specific website so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: *"into text boxes"* - Any particular textbox(es)? Is there an id or class by which the textbox might be selected?

Comment: It's a forum reply. Similar to this one. This website: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community

Comment: So, again, is there an id or class, or other means by which the relevant textbox might be selected? (Or is there only one on the page?) What code have you tried so far?